# Switching between classes and passing results

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to add different PlugLead's to the PlugBoard and extract the combination. In the first class I am extracting the one letter from the list should they match or return the input. e.g.

```
lead = PlugLead("AG")
assert(lead.encode("A") == "G")
```

```
class PlugLead:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
        
    def encode(self, l):
        c0 = self.c[0]
        c1 = self.c[1]
        if len(l) == 1 and c0 == l:
            return c1
        elif len(l) == 1 and c1 == l:
            return c0
        else:
            return l
        
class Plugboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = 0
        self.leads = []
        self.c = []
    
    def add(self, item):
        if self.__head >= 10:
            print("leads already got 10 items")
        elif item in self.leads:
            print(f"leads already have this item: {item}")
        else:
            self.leads.append(item)
            self.__head += 1
        return self.leads

    def encode(self)
        lines = plugboard.leads
        for word in lines:
            word = word.split(",")
            PlugLead.encode(word)
```

In the second class I am trying to add multiple combinations and then at the end pass the one letter to see what its match is in the Class PlugLead however am not able to switch between the two. In the class PlugLead I have a add function that allows the different combinations to be added up to 10 and then I would like to encode from this list the combination of the pairs. e.g.

```
plugboard = Plugboard()

plugboard.add(PlugLead("SZ"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("GT"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("DV"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("KU"))

assert(plugboard.encode("K") == "U")
assert(plugboard.encode("A") == "A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you want to use `PlugLead("{balabala}")`,you need use `__new__` to return a `dict` when you create an instance, not `__init__`.
- you want a key-value pair in `Plugboard`, it should be a `dict` not `list`
- fix some other typo and bugs.

code:

```
class PlugLead:
    def __new__(self, c):
        return {c[0]:c[1]}
        
class Plugboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = 0
        self.leads = {}
    
    def add(self, item):
        if self.__head >= 10:
            print("leads already got 10 items")
        elif list(item.keys())[0] in self.leads.keys():
            print(f"leads already have this item: {item}")
        else:
            self.leads.update(item)
            self.__head += 1
        return self.leads

    def encode(self,key):
        if key in self.leads:
            return self.leads[key]
        elif key in self.leads.values():
            return list(self.leads.keys())[list(self.leads.values()).index(key)]
        return key

plugboard = Plugboard()
plugboard.add(PlugLead("SZ"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("GT"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("DV"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("KU"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("KU"))

assert(plugboard.encode("K") == "U")
assert(plugboard.encode("U") == "K")
assert(plugboard.encode("A") == "A")

print(plugboard.encode("K"))
print(plugboard.encode("U"))
print(plugboard.encode("A"))
```

result:

```
leads already have this item: {'K': 'U'}
U
K
A
```

Comment: Thank you lead_yakitori for the elaboration and the solution to this challenge, it helps tremendously when trying to learn Python and getting feedback like you, thank you